# NSNumberFormatter and CurrencyFormatter issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

So i have an app which has a UILabel and a UITextfield.

In the UITextField Object, a user inputs something like this in this format:

```
  EXAMPLE 1:                      1300.00
```

and with the use of NSNumberformatter with the NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle, It displays the
correct output to the UILabel named: displayValue.

```
  EXAMPLE 2:      displayValue    $1,300.00
```

However, i am saving this Value in a NSUserDefaults object. So saved it goes and the app closes and i reopen it. Since the UITextfield saves the Inputed value to STAY there as typed before like in EXAMPLE 1:,  in which a user can quickly EDIT the value, instead, i get the newly formatted number exactly like in EXAMPLE 2 but with the $ symbol and the comma after the 1 and editing this number to lets say, changing the 1 to a 2 to results in setting the Value in the UILabel to:

```
   EXAMPLE 3       displayValue     $0.00
```

BUT if i go into the UITextfield and remove the $ Symbol and the (,) Comma after the 2, it displays the Value as i want:

```
  EXAMPLE 4:       displayValue     $2,300.00
```

So my question is, is there a way i can avoid having the $ symbol on the UITextfield without having to take it manually? same applies to the comma, which i dont want to remove it everytime i remove the $ symbol to get format like EXAMPLE 1.

Overall, The value has to be displayed like in EXAMPLE 4 formatted with the $ and the comma separating the numbers but not in the UITextfield because it results in displaying something like in EXAMPLE 3 to a total $0.00 when editing the saved number and hitting save.

Here is a Bit of the code: weeklyPay is the UITextField:

```
      float FInteger = [weeklyPay.text floatValue];


/* =============================Formatter================================== */

NSNumberFormatter *formatter =
                              [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];


NSString *formattedInteger = [formatter stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: FInteger]];

/* ================================================================================*/
/* Display the Saved week onto UILabel */

self.displayValue.text = formattedInteger; // DisplayValue is the UIlabel
```

Here is the way i save the data inputed:

```
    NSUserDefaults *savedData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [savedData setObject: formattedInteger forKey:@"weeklyPay"];
    NSLog(@"%@", formattedInteger);
    [savedData synchronize];
```

Here is the way i retrieve and display the Data to the UIlabel called displayValue and also keeps the typed Value in the UITextfield like a Placeholder but editable:

In ViewDidLoad Method:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.displayValue.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"weeklyPay"];

    // This retains the value of the UItextField

    NSString *placeholder = [defaults stringForKey:@"weeklyPay"];

    weeklyPay.text = placeholder;

    /* Become first Responder conditionally */
    if ([weeklyPay.text isEqualToString: placeholder])
    {

    // Do Nothing if the UItextfield is filled with Numbers
     }
     else {

        [addFundsField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```

Any Suggestions or any way i can accomplish this ?

Comment: anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: So does anyone have something? i heard something with NSRange but not sure how to use it